# RTypeProvider ChainLadder Package build triangle

Tags: f#, type-providers, deedle

I am trying to create a triangle in `F#` using `RTypeProvider`, with the following code:

```
let years = [ 1981; 1982; 1983; 1984; 1985; 1986; 1987; 1988; 1990; 1991 ]
let t1 = [ 5012; 106; 3410; 5655; 1092; 1513; 557; 1351; 3133; 2063 ]
let t2 = [ 8269; 4285; 8992; 11555; 9565; 6445; 4020; 6947; 5395]
let t3 = [ 10907; 5396; 13873; 15766; 15836; 11702; 10946; 13112]
let t4 = [ 11805; 10666; 16141; 21266; 22169; 12935; 12314]
let t5 = [ 13539; 13782; 18735; 23425; 25955; 15852]
let t6 = [ 16181; 15599; 22214; 26083; 26180]
let t7 = [ 18009; 15496; 22863; 27067]
let t8 = [ 18608; 16169; 23466]
let t9 = [ 18662; 16704]
let t10 = [ 18834 ]
let fAAA = Frame(["1";"2";"3";"4";"5";"6";"7";"8";"9";"10"],[Series(years, t1); Series(years, t2); Series(years, t3); Series(years, t4); Series(years, t5); Series(years, t6); Series(years, t7); Series(years, t8); Series(years, t9); Series(years, t10)])

let MAAA = ChainLadder.R.as_triangle(fAAA, origin="origin", dev="dev", value="value")
```

I get an error that starts with

> "arguments imply a different number of rows"

It is because it has some missing values. But the missing values are needed because otherwise it will perform the calculations incorrectly. I also use `Deedle`.

Comment: Why don't you create a triangle in R directly and use `ChainLadder` package to handle it.